# Spectral radius of Fredholm integral operator on $L^1$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request

Let $W\in L^\infty[0,1]^2$ be a symmetric function, i.e. $W(x,y)\equiv W(y,x)$. Consider the Fredholm integral operator $$T:L^1[0,1]\to L^1[0,1]:f(\cdot)\mapsto\int_0^1 W(\cdot,y)f(y) \ \mathrm dy.$$ I'd like to determine the spectral radius $\rho(T)$. I know that under those conditions $T$ is a compact, self-adjoint operator, hence the spectrum is countable, contains $0$, and apart from $0$ only consists of eigenvalues. Hence when $f$ is an eigenfunction corresponding to eigenvalue, $\lambda\neq0$, then $$\lambda f(x)=\int_0^1W(x,y)f(y)\ \mathrm dy\leq \|W\|_{L^\infty}\|f\|_{L^1},$$ whence $\lambda\|f\|_{L^1}\leq \|W\|_{L^\infty}\|f\|_{L^1}$, whence $\rho(T)\leq \|W\|_{L^\infty}$. Furthermore, if $W$ is a constant function, equality clearly holds, by taking $f$ a non-zero constant function. In particular, in contrast to many similar situations, $\sigma(T)\neq\{0\}$, in general.

However, how can we find this nonzero spectral radius in general? Is there some general method, or some explicit dependency on the kernel $W$? If not, I would be very interested in particular cases or classes of examples for $W$ in which more can be said. Any help or reference is much appreciated.